# How to query on greater than date in mongoose.?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Hope everyone is doing great.

I was querying on one collection (let's say User), where I wanted to fetch record based on date (records, whose expiry date is greater from today's date).

I was writing a query in nodejs (mongoose) something like below -

```
   const user = await User.find({
    subscriptionExpiryDate: {$gte: new Date()},
   });
```

and in mongoose console I'm getting the query something like this -

```
   Mongoose: users.find({ subscriptionExpiryDate: { '$gte': new Date("Thu, 02 Apr 2020 14:59:38 GMT") } }, { projection: {} })
```

and I'm getting response as null array []. While the database has records, which are satisfying the query search criteria.

Can anyone please tell me where I'm doing wrong.?

Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: show db records as well

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm late but this might help others.
use `getTime()` in query. for example:

```
    const d=new Date();
    const user = await User.find({
        subscriptionExpiryDate: {$gte: d.getTime()},
   });
```

This work for me

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Vikas :) This will help others surely.